# PHP Using cookies to log in

Tags: php, http, cookies, curl

I am trying to log into a page through curl. Where a successful login redirects you to the actual site and you see the content there.

Basically, there is are 2 urls, the first url is to post the login credentials to and the other url is where the content is visible after the login.

I managed to send a post request to the login url and it successfully creates a valid cookie too but I can't figure out how to use the cookie to see the content of the page from the second url.

I am trying to do a normal curl request (without the `POSTFIELDS` in the code) with these two options to retrieve the content of page 2 but if you view the source for it, it just displays the html code to redirect to the login url.

```
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Some more code would be useful, as any number of things in both requests could be causing this problem.

Comment: Please see the comment in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try to add more parameters to your CURL request :

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; en-US)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$string = curl_exec ($ch);  
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: All of these are currently there but when I pass in the url the content that is returned is the html code to redirect to the login page. Implying that the cookie was not passed on. This is why I am confused

Comment: So it's better to give us the site you'r trying to access , we can do our tests and return back with the correct answer

Comment: I am now using the exact code you just pasted to first login. Your code up there sets the cookie perfectly. Now I am trying to get the contents of the page that requires this cookie in order to display the content. I would give you the URL but you cant get anywhere with it because you wont be able to get login credentials to it.